# How to sort an array into columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multiple-columns

I need help organizing an array in java. The code below prints out random numbers in a straight line. However, I want the code to print out four of those numbers and then continue on a new line. Essential, I want the code to print out four random numbers on the first line, then another 4 random numbers on the second, and so on and so forth.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SelectionSort{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] array = new int[200];

        Random rand = new Random();

        // for acsending order
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 



        array[i] = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.print("\n");


        // for descending order

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want broken into 4-number lines: the ascending output, the descending output, or both?

Comment: `StringBuilder`, `StringJoiner` and/or `String.format` would be my recommendations

Comment: Please use curly braces around the for loop body, especially if you format the code like this.

Comment: Both, @TedHopp , and thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print `\n` for each 4 numbers

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SelectionSort { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[200];

        Random rand = new Random();

        // for acsending order
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            array[i] = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
        }

        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.print("\n");


        // for descending order

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
            if (i % 4 == 0) { 
                // print \n for each 4 numbers.
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but what if I also want the ascending output to be in four columns as well. Again, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Sebastian - Use the same technique: an explicit loop with an index that you test. You can't use `Arrays.toString(array)` to do what you want.